# Is it possible to make jFace TreeViewer specific node support bold font for its LabelProvider?

Tags: eclipse-rcp, jface, eclipse-plugin

I'm developing a tree based on TreeViewer and created myLabelProvider which `extends LabelProvider` and then use `viewer.setLabelProvider(new ViewLabelProvider());`, but all the nodes are still displayed with normal plain style.

Code:

```
class ViewLabelProvider extends LabelProvider implements ITableLabelProvider, ITableFontProvider{

    public String getText(Object obj) {
        return obj.toString();
    }

    public Image getImage(Object obj) {
        return null;
    }

    public Font getFont(Object element, int columnIndex) {
        FontRegistry registry = new FontRegistry();
        return registry.getBold(Display.getCurrent().getSystemFont().getFontData()[0].getName());
    }

    public Image getColumnImage(Object element, int columnIndex) {
        return null;
    }

    public String getColumnText(Object element, int columnIndex) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

References:

http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t95078.html
[How do I make part of a TreeViewer cell bold?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20170899/how-do-i-make-part-of-a-treeviewer-cell-bold)

Can anyone give some advice?

Comment: Are you using multiple columns or a single column?

Comment: @greg-449 No columns. It's just a hierarchy tree like the `Package Explorer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just using a single column then make your label provider implement `IFontProvider` (and perhaps `IColorProvider`)

```java
public Font getFont(Object element) {
   return font or null to use default
}
```

Note: If you create any fonts be sure to dispose of them when your are done.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
public String getColumnText(Object element, int columnIndex)
{
 if (columnIndex == 0)
  return getText(element);
 return null;
}
```

Comment: the 3 methods `getFont` `getColumnImage` `getColumnText` is never called in my labelProvider

Comment: Do you have columns in your TreeViewer? Is it constructed by TreeViewer(Tree tree) constructor, where tree has several columns? If no, maybe you need just IFontProvider

Comment: I don't have columns in my tree. It's just a hierarchy tree like the `Package Explorer` tree.